# Parsing Json with Newtonsoft getting error

Tags: c#, json, parsing, windows-phone-8

On a web service call i get the following response

```
   {
   "132800000000040": {
      "likes": 38347,
      "id": "132800000000040"
   },
   "192011111111130": {
      "likes": 44855,
      "id": "192011111111130"
   },
   "115372222222226": {
      "likes": 42227,
      "id": "115372222222226"
   },
   "186111111111116": {
      "likes": 21987,
      "id": "186111111111116"
   },
   "30000000002": {
      "likes": 18539,
      "id": "30000000002"
   },
   "24000000006": {
      "likes": 16438,
      "id": "24000000006"
   }
}
```

I created a class to hold data

```
public class LikeCount
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string likes { get; set; }
}
```

and tried to parse the json as follows

```
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
List<LikeCount> LikeList = (List<LikeCount>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj.ToString(), typeof(List<LikeCount>));
```

But getting the error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Rxz.Model.LikeCount]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

How can i fix this please help..

Comment: This is not a collection. Collections are delimited by `[]`. Yet you're trying to deserialize into a collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON element is an object, as it's delimited by `{ }`, not an array which would be delimited by `[ ]`. So you can't just deserialize it into a `List`.

Your object has key-value pairs, `string` being the key and your `LikeCount` being the value. As such, you should deserialize it to an [`IDictionary<string, LikeCount>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IDictionary<string, LikeCount> dict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, LikeCount>>(responseString);
```

If you only need a list of your `LikeCount` objects without the keys, you can then get them using the [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.values(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Then, depending on your needs, you may or may not need to convert it to a `List` via [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IDictionary<string, LikeCount> dict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, LikeCount>>(responseString);
List<LikeCount> likes = dict.Values.ToList();
```